# What is a post decoder?

Tags: digital-logic, logic-gates, cmos, decoder, sram

I have heard a bit about pre decoders and post decoders recently in circuit design. When I saw the circuits, the pre decoder is same as the normal decoder in every textbook or website. But I haven't seen the post decoder anywhere. I have pasted a copy of its circuit. Can anyone explain?? [image]

Comment: where does the circuit come from?

Comment: A report from college.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the general memory architecture, predecoder is used to optimize selection of the wordline. In addition to row address decoding, the wordline selection circuit needs clocking (which cannot be done in the predecoder circuits because of skew danger); it also provides wordline driving (WL output).

What you see in the pasted picture (from left to right), is a decode gate IC6 (three-input NAND), a buffer (inverter) IC5, a clocking gate IC4 (two-input NAND) and three-buffer chain IC3, IC2, IC1 which minimizes buffer delay by distributing logical effort through constituent inverters. All these components are typical constituents of a final wordline decoder.

Judging by this picture, it appears that the "postdecoder" circuit is just a final wordline decoder circuit.

Comment: Okay. Thanks a lot for the explanation.

Comment: But can you please elaborate on what you mean by optimising the selection of wordline??

Comment: see a textbook or coursenotes on RAM address decoders, for example, http://pages.hmc.edu/harris/class/e158/01/lect12.pdf, specifically slides 10 to 18.

Comment: Thanks for this link.